# Get parameter from the url in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, window.location

Well I have a problem. I am using now a factory to handle dtas for two controllers in my app. When I click to a link, it routes me to another view with a specific url, which last tag I want to reuse, so I'm trying to slice it like

```
window.location.pathname.split("/").slice(-1)[0]
```

but it seems to be not working, and saying: $location is undefined :/
Anyone ideas on how to solve this? Maybe a trivial error what I made but... the more eyes sees more :)

```
portApp.controller("itemController", ["$scope", "workFactory",
    function($scope, workFactory, $stateParams) {

        console.log(window.location.pathname.split("/").slice(-1)[0]);
        $location.path(); // it says $location is undefined in the console

        var newpath = $stateParams.itemLink;
        $scope.onViewLoad = function(){
            console.log(newpath);
        };
    }
]);
```

Here is the jsfiddle for it - https://jsfiddle.net/d5bjrjov/

Comment: $location is undefined because you've not injected it as dependency

Comment: Don't forget to add the relevant code block into the question. `$location` is undefined because you haven't added it as a dependency. Same with `$stateParams`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller, you've not injected `$location` that;s why it's showing `$location` is undefined.

```
portApp.controller("itemController", ["$scope", "workFactory",
    function($scope, workFactory, $stateParams) {
```

must be

```
portApp.controller("itemController", ["$scope", "workFactory", '$stateParams', '$location',
    function($scope, workFactory, $stateParams, $location) {
```

> In your State Provider

You have

```
 .state('items', {
                url: '/items/{itemLink}',
                controller: 'itemController'
            });
```

The URL pattern is wrong. When you want to have dynamic data in your URL you must use `:itemLink` as the pattern.

```
 .state('items', {
                    url: '/items/:itemLink',
                    controller: 'itemController'
                });
```

In your controller, you can get it using `$stateParams`

```
$stateParams.itemLink
```

Comment: I am now using the injected $location and console says for $location.path() -> TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined

Comment: I've updated the answer. Could you please try again? Also if possible setup a jsfiddle with necessary code so that we can test

Comment: Thank you mohamed, I saw that using this bracket forms stand that there will be always value with the same format. That parts seemingly working unmodified. Updated my code, and my jsfiddle too, still getting the error. - https://jsfiddle.net/d5bjrjov/3/

Comment: In your current code also there is a mismatch in dependencies.  `["$scope", "workFactory", "$location",
        function($scope, workFactory, $stateParams, $location) {` It must be `["$scope", "workFactory", "$stateParams", "$location",
        function($scope, workFactory, $stateParams, $location) {`

Comment: Yea.. thank you. I am reading a lot of Angular, including sources but sometimes get lost in the woods :) It helped me out :) Now coming the filter part inside the factory =)))